# Rest API design, storing access tokens

Tags: api, rest

I'm trying to wrap my head around restful API design on a bigger scale than one simple installation.

My setup would look something like his:
[image: Rest]

The question is, after a user has been authorized to do requests they get the access token. Should EVERY following request first go to the proxy, then to the auth server to check the token and finally get the data from the resource server?

Considering you need somewhere to store the users permissions/roles on what URIs he is allowed to use.

I was thinking if you move the tokens and the permission/roles to the rest proxy. Stored in a memory cache like Redis? And when a permission/role is updated on the auth server, it pushes those changes to the proxy. The proxy would not need to make additional calls to the auth server every single time reducing it to just 1 call to the resource server. Or maybe this is how everyone does it, two internal calls every request?

Answer (score 0):

It is not a great idea to authenticate the token on every request. Instead , save the token in some fashion either in Redis or in a map on your resource server whose expiry time can be set in synch with the token expiry time.

Using Redis you can store these tokens along with the role against a single key say userId and set token's expiration time(by setting the expiry time of a key) .In this way once the token expires the calls will automatically be redirected to the authentication server on its own.

User roles and permissions should be saved on the resource server either as a separate set in Redis for maintaining permissions list to check against the user role which you will pick from Redis again (or depending on how you rest API facilitates setting permissions on resources as certain Rest API facilitators have inbuilt APIs for restricting resources via annotations). This permission list can be updated as and when modified.

Comment: But I would also need to store the users ACL (which particular resources hes allowed to access) in Redis?